# Ways of Safari App Extension to communicate with containing app

Tags: swift, macos, safari-app-extension

I have a **Safari App Extension** that injects a button over images into a specific website and when tapping that button I want to trigger a function with some parameters in the application that contains the safari app extension (**NOT** from .js to extension handler)

How can I communicate from the Safari App Extension with the main app in real time? `NSUserDefaults` trough app groups does not seems a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If you don't (can't) listen to updates of "shared user defaults" (using a group SuiteName).
Then you may try with Distributed Notifications:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/distributednotificationcenter

It's quite simple and similar to messaging between Content Scripts and Safari App Extension.